# How to vectorize (using Numpy/Pandas) my nested if statement under nested for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, nested-loops

I am trying to compare two DataFrames ,I wish to efficiently use `pandas (or numpy)` instead of a nested for loop with an if statement in it to solve a particular problem. Below is a small sniffet of my program.

```
spindleload = {'time': ['2020-02-03 00:18:07', '2020-02-03 00:18:08', '2020-02-03 00:18:09', '2020-02-03 00:18:10', '2020-02-03 00:18:11', '2020-02-03 00:18:12', '2020-02-03 00:18:13', '2020-02-03 00:18:14', '2020-02-03 00:18:15', '2020-02-03 00:18:16', '2020-02-03 00:18:17'], 
               'value': [17,25,14,14,22,22,22,22,22,12,19]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=spindleload) 


cycletime = {'newtimestart': ['2020-02-03 00:18:08','2020-02-03 00:18:13'], 'newtimeend': ['2020-02-03 00:18:11', '2020-02-03 00:18:15']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=cycletime)
```

Now I wish to loop it to get **time** and **value** in **df1** for the corresponding values in between **newtimestart** and **newtimeend** in **df2**. Below is the code.

```
output_graph_time = []
output_graph_value = []

for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        if df1['time'][j] >= df2['newtimestart'][i]:
            output_graph_time.append(df1['time'][j])
            output_graph_value.append(df1['value'][j])  
            if df1['time'][j] == df2['newtimeend'][i]:
                break
print(output_graph_time)
print(output_graph_value)
```

Now here the code is working fine, but when it reads millions of rows of data it is unable to execute, also i tried implementing `Numba`, But the kernel was unable to handle and used to get restarted.
Hence I request to solve this using **Numpy** or **Pandas vectorization** method.

Further to this, when I tried with applying vectorization method i found difficulty in breaking if condition after every execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do convert df2 in a daterange and explode , then using `isin` filter df1.

Convert to datetime from strings (*Ignore this step is values are already datetimes*)

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Map as `pd.date_range` and `explode` , then filter using `isin`

```
out = (df1[df1['time'].isin(df2.agg(tuple,1).map(lambda x: 
                  pd.date_range(*x,freq='s')).explode())])
```

---

```
print(out)

                 time  value
1 2020-02-03 00:18:08     25
2 2020-02-03 00:18:09     14
3 2020-02-03 00:18:10     14
4 2020-02-03 00:18:11     22
6 2020-02-03 00:18:13     22
7 2020-02-03 00:18:14     22
8 2020-02-03 00:18:15     22
```

Which is similar to your output:

```
print(output_graph_time)
print(output_graph_value)

['2020-02-03 00:18:08', '2020-02-03 00:18:09', '2020-02-03 00:18:10', 
'2020-02-03 00:18:11', '2020-02-03 00:18:13', '2020-02-03 00:18:14', 
 '2020-02-03 00:18:15']

[25, 14, 14, 22, 22, 22, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `df1` is several millions of rows. If your `df2` is not to big, you can do a cross merge:

```
(df1.assign(dummy=1)
    .merge(df2.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')
    .query('newtimestart<=time<=newtimeend')
)
```

Output:

```
                   time  value
2   2020-02-03 00:18:08     25
4   2020-02-03 00:18:09     14
6   2020-02-03 00:18:10     14
8   2020-02-03 00:18:11     22
13  2020-02-03 00:18:13     22
15  2020-02-03 00:18:14     22
17  2020-02-03 00:18:15     22
```